# Why do minecraft crash questions get "unclear" close votes

Tags: discussion, minecraft

I notice questions [like this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184036/crash-on-startup-with-open-blocks-1-7-10-on-technic-launcher) tend to draw close votes of "Unclear what your asking".

I understand I don't have to vote to close (I actually can't remember if I have voted to close these questions for that reason) and voting is up to the opinion of each user who has enough Rep to vote but I am wondering, is it really so unclear not to understand that the the intent of the question is how to get Minecraft working again?

Or is "Unclear what your asking" the go to close reason for very poor quality questions (ie. not enough details are given thus we close it)

Comment: The way I see it is the question is (majority of the time) "Minecraft's broken, I think this is important [crash dump]". What happened? When did it happen? Were you doing anything else? Drivers, stats etc. IMO, I'd prefer to know more than just what broke before I (can) answer a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave the answer yourself. These questions get closed because not enough details are given. And that results in an unclear question.

Sometimes a crashdump is enough, more often it isn't though. You'll almost always also see a comment asking for more information at these questions too.

The question you posted doesn't warrant these closevotes I think. This is one of the better ones. More often then not, these question are a simple case of copy+paste crashdump and no extra information. And that's not enough to be useful.

So in short: I think the question you used as an example should not be closed, it could use some extra info, but there is enough information available to try to reconstruct the situation. Most of these questions with just a crashdump *are* unclear though, and need to be closed.

Comment: In addition, many of the users who post these questions never return with the information we need, so we end up with a ton of unanswerable questions.